# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:" xxx "

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-webapps

I have a use case for a project where I need to automate the creation of Application Registration on Azure programmatically.
I have been using this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2-signInAndCallGraph).

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7FpS.png)

We seem to be facing an issue with Authentication for this App Registration code. We have checked the ReplyURLs with the urls in our App Settings. They are the same. What may be another reason for this occuring?

We also found another link on microsoft documentation where this thread seems to be open but have not found a solution there either. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/54102/the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-does-not-ma.html

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi, has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this kind of problem, you can try a general solution:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request url, you will find `redirect_url`, copy the value of `redirect_url` and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with `http`, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.